# De Morgan law, square equation negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi could you help me with the negation of the following statement using De Morgan law?

$$∀x∈\mathbb R, x^2+x+1=x+5.$$

Comment: What does $\wedge$ mean in this context?  Usually, it means and, which does not make sense here.  Did you mean $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} x^2 + x + 1 = x + 5$?

Comment: Yes exactly, I have edited the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $$x^2+x+1=x+5 \iff x^2=4 \iff x=2 \space \text{or} \space x=-2$$
The negation of $\forall$ is $\exists$, so you get
$$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}: x\neq 2 \space \text{and} \space x\neq -2$$

Comment: The negation of $\forall x, P$ is $\exists x, \neg P$.  Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, I have written the solution.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is following.

1. False statement i.e x = 0
   $$∀x∈\mathbb R, x^2+x+1=x+5.$$
2. Negation De Morgan Law
   $$\lnot∀x∈\mathbb R, x^2+x+1=x+5.$$
   $$\exists x∈\mathbb R, \lnot (x^2+x+1 = x+5).$$
3. True statement i.e x = 0
   $$\exists x∈\mathbb R, x^2+x+1\neq x+5.$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.